# Can we upload a photo to the facebook album using the profile ID in

Tags: facebook

I wanted to upload a photo to s specific facebook account, for which the credentials are open to our developer. When user does some action it shd trigger this method and a photo has to uploaded to the specific facebook account.

Can anyone please share your idea...

Regards,
Harlborn

Answer (score 0):

I hate to post a URL as an answer but literally googling your question provided this answer:  https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

In short - Use the facebook grap API